# How to add a UIBarButtonItem of custom width to a UINavigationItem programmatically without using an image

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, width, uibarbuttonitem

I'm using iOS 6.1 and want to add a UIBarButtonItem of **custom width** with title "Info" to the UINavigationItem programmatically when the view loads. **I don't want to use an image to achieve this.**

I read several threads about how to change the width of a UIBarButtonItem and none seem to work for me.

I tried this but the button does not appear:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIView *infoButtonView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 44)];
    UIBarButtonItem *infoButton2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:infoButtonView];

    [infoButton2 setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered];
    [infoButton2 setTitle:@"Info"];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = infoButton2;
}
```

What's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 2):

```
//This worked for me    
UIButton *searchButton =[[UIButton alloc]init];
        searchButton.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 40);
        [searchButton setTitle:@"Info" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         searchButton.backgroundColor= [UIColor greenColor];
        [searchButton addTarget:self action:@selector(onFilter) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        UIBarButtonItem *searchBarButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:searchButton] ;
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = searchBarButton;
```

Comment: This is good, but the button is now a green rectangle. How can I add the look&feel of the original button? I only wanted to change the width.

Comment: add properties like color,border,or another properties to add look and feel ,,you can do any thing with this UIButton *searchButton ,,like u can do with normal button.

Comment: Adding all the properties of a standard bar button item (the one that you can drag&drop from the Object library onto the Storyboard) to a custom one for all its different statuses is not a trivial task. I'm surprised there's not a simpler way to simply change the width property.

Answer (score 0):

you can also add button just like this..

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
      UIView *infoButtonView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 50, 44)];
        [infoButtonView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

        UIButton *button1 = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,15,45,21)];
        [button1 setTitle:@"Info" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button1.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
        [infoButtonView addSubview:button1];

        UIBarButtonItem *infoButton2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:infoButtonView];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = infoButton2;
    }
```

Comment: This is good, but the button is now a red rectangle. How can I add the look&feel of the original button? I only wanted to change the width.

Comment: UIView *infoButtonView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 100, 44)];
    [infoButtonView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    UIButton *button1 =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];[button1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0,15,90,21)];
button1.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
[button1 setTitle:@"Info" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button1.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
[infoButtonView addSubview:button1];       
UIBarButtonItem *infoButton2=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:infoButtonView];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = infoButton2;